# Delete blank rows from Excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I have code the merges multiple excel workbooks together, and updates the data into another workbook "Master", however, when it paste the data into the master it leaves numerous blank rows prior to the insert of the data table.

I have tried various posted solutions, however, when I incorporate the new code it is failing.  I could use some assistances in modifying my code to handle the removal of the inserted blank rows in my table, prior to the data being updated.

See '>>>>>>>>> marked in the code.

```
Public Function MergeMultipleSheets()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim myBook As Workbook, wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim rng As Range, SearchValue As String
    Dim FilterField As Integer, RangeAddress As String
    Dim ShName As Variant, ShNames As Variant, RwCount As Long, nName As Variant
    Dim nFilter As String
    Dim currentrow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input").Range("B1")
 '   ShNames = Array("ProjSum", "FinSum", "CommSum", "InvPlan", "ResPlan_Data")
    ShNames = Array("ProjSum", "ResPlan_Data")

    Set wbMaster = ActiveWorkbook
    '**********************************************************
    'Merge data into existing worksheets in this workbook
    '**********************************************************

    ' Add a slash after MyPath if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If
   ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    'FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "week*.xl*")

    nFilter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Input").Range("B2")
    If nFilter = "" Or FilesInPath = "" Then
        FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    End If

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files in the
    ' folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Change application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
        ' Clear data from summary worksheets
        For Each ShName In ShNames
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = wbMaster.Worksheets(ShName).UsedRange
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                'Don't delete header labels in the first row
                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next

    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set myBook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set myBook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum), UpdateLinks:=0)

        '**************************************************************************************************
        'Removes unused Named Ranges from Name Manager from the Various JC files to prevent error dialogs.
        '**************************************************************************************************
               For Each nName In Names
                    If InStr(1, nName.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then
                        nName.Delete
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, nName.RefersTo, "https://") > 0 Then
                        nName.Delete
                    End If
                Next nName
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not myBook Is Nothing Then

                For Each ShName In ShNames
                    Set ws = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set ws = myBook.Worksheets(ShName)
                    On Error GoTo 0
     '****************************************************************************************************************************
    'Calls function to update ResPlan in active workbook
    'Executes Updating of the ResPlan data to proper format for extraction of data in correct format
    '****************************************************************************************************************************
                    If ShName = "ResPlan_Data" Then
                        Call UnpivotResPlan
                        myBook.Save
                    End If

                        '**************************************************
                        'Updates template data per shName
                        '*************************************************
'>>>>>>>>>
                        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                            Set BaseWks = wbMaster.Worksheets(ShName)
                            Set sourceRange = ws.UsedRange
                            'Exclude header labels
                            Set rng = sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceRange.Columns.Count)
                                rng.ClearContents
Dim rngBlanks As Excel.Range

    With wbMaster.Worksheets(ShName).ListObjects("Res_Plan_Data")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngBlanks = Intersect(.DataBodyRange, .ListColumns("New").Range).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngBlanks Is Nothing Then
            rngBlanks.Delete
        End If
    End With
                            RwCount = rng.Rows.Count
                            rnum = BaseWks.Cells(BaseWks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A").Resize(RwCount).Value _
                                  = myBook.Name
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Resize(RwCount, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
                        End If
                Next

               ' Close the workbook without saving.
                 myBook.Close savechanges:=True
             End If

            ' Open the next workbook.
        Next FNum

        ' Set the column width in the new workbook.
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit

        'Prepares Salary Detail for Updating.
        Call UnpivotSalaryDetail

    End If
        Call Reset
       ' ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh

        If Worksheets("Resplan_Data").Visible = True Then
            Worksheets("Resplan_Data").Visible = False
        End If
        MsgBox "Update completed!"

    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Function


Sub ClearBlankCellsInColumnNew()
Dim rngBlanks As Excel.Range

    With Worksheets("ResPlan_Data").ListObjects("Res_Plan_Data")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngBlanks = Intersect(.DataBodyRange, .ListColumns("New").Range).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngBlanks Is Nothing Then
            rngBlanks.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after but it will delete all the rows which have a blank cell in column A

```
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

A quick explination `Columns("A:A")` is the target column, change the letter and add numbers or varibles as you wish. `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` is what cell it will target, in this case it will be the blank cells (record a macro and press `Ctrl + G` for any variations you need). And lastly `.EntireRow.Delete` will delete the target row(s).

So it will look in column A, and if there is any blank cells in column A it will delete that row.

Hope this helps, leave a comment if you need anything clarifed

Comment: I need to delete blank rows not columns and I tried the .entirerow.delete, my problem is the proper syntax using my current code.  Please help with the correct syntax. I insert the code from another example, but doesn't seem that I need that.

I need to modify or add to the following line of code to allow for the deletion of blank rows, prior to the data being updated:

Comment: @Karen Schaefer , this doesnt delete the column, it check the whole column for any blank cells, any blank cells it finds it will delete that row

Comment: here is where I need to delete the blank rows that seem to be added, prior to the append of the data to the worksheet:

                            Set rng = sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceRange.Columns.Count)

is there away to post a attachment to this comment?
                                rng.ClearContents

Comment: Set rng = sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceRange.Columns.Count)
                                rng.ClearContents
                                rng.EntireRow.Delete
                            RwCount = rng.Rows.Count
                        I tried this but the code has issues with


Object required error

Comment: If you are using `rng.ClearContents` why not just change it to `rng.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: I need to clear the contents and then remove any blank rows.  for some reason my code does not want to post the results in column A2 each time it seems to want to add columns then goes to the end of the columns then appends the data.

Is there a way to post attachments on this website?\

Comment: Which row are you going down when you are doing the `rng.CLearContents`?

Comment: Turns out the code has issue with the:  RwCount = rng.Rows.Count

sorry don't know how to place the code in grey area, in this section:

       Set rng = sourceRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 1, sourceRange.Columns.Count)
                                rng.EntireRow.Delete
                            RwCount = rng.Rows.Count

Comment: to give text the grey back ground use ` `before` and `after` the `text`

Comment: How do I post an attachment here?

Comment: Cant in comments, http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting is what you can do in comments

Comment: Mr Burns,  thanks for your assistance.

Should I open a new question regarding modifying my code to make sure that the data is always placed in the table area of the worksheet?

Comment: Yea that would be a new question